# creating an incidence plot with specific data format

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create and incidence plot and an epidemic curve using the incidence() command. I have the following data [where I should be using data_use (class = Date) and new_case (class = int) for the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaS5O.png). I am using the following code:

`library(incidence)`

`i <- incidence(outbreak, interval = 1)`

`plot(i, border = "white")`

However, I am getting an error: Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list' when I run the second line. Is there a way to create the incidence plot using this data format and command? I appreciate the help!

P.S. [Here is an example of the plot I am trying to generate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSJdH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has to do with what the `incidence` function expects as arguments. According to help `?incidence` the first argument `dates` is:

> A vector of dates, which can be provided as objects of the class:
> integer, numeric, Date, POSIXct, POSIXlt, and character. (See Note
> about numeric and character formats)

It is not entirely clear if `outbreak` is, but presumably a data frame (list of columns) containing the data in your image? The error message probably comes from providing a data frame instead of a vector of dates.

If you do have a data frame such as the example:

```
     date_use total_cases new_case
1  2020-03-01         168       25
2  2020-03-02         187       19
3  2020-03-03         200       13
4  2020-03-04         219       19
5  2020-03-05         252       33
6  2020-03-06         295       43
7  2020-03-07         336       41
8  2020-03-08         383       47
9  2020-03-09         470       87
10 2020-03-10         566       96
11 2020-03-11         698      132
```

You could create a vector of dates based on `date_use` and `new_case`:

```
my_dates <- rep(df$date_use, df$new_case)

table(my_dates)
my_dates
2020-03-01 2020-03-02 2020-03-03 2020-03-04 2020-03-05 2020-03-06 2020-03-07 2020-03-08 2020-03-09 
        25         19         13         19         33         43         41         47         87 
2020-03-10 2020-03-11 
        96        132
```

Then you can use `incidence` as follows to create the incidence object:

```
i <- incidence(my_dates, interval = 1)

i
<incidence object>
[555 cases from days 2020-03-01 to 2020-03-11]

$counts: matrix with 11 rows and 1 columns
$n: 555 cases in total
$dates: 11 dates marking the left-side of bins
$interval: 1 day
$timespan: 11 days
$cumulative: FALSE
```

And then plot:

```
plot(i, border = "white")
```

[image: incidence plot]